# External jar configuration when debugging JSP in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Using tomcat 7.0.11 and eclipse 3.6.1.

I'm trying to debug a jsp file that uses log4j but I get a class not found error at runtime because tomcat isn't seeing log4j-1.2.16.jar. When I was running outside of eclipse I had to add a reference to all external jars in catalina.properties. Is there a way for me to specify this runtime reference in eclipse?

Update:
Here are screenshots of my current settings: 
[image: screenshot 1]

[image]

With the settings like this the tomcat catalina.properties file gets overwritten when I start up tomcat in eclipse (which wipes out the changes I made to shared.loader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the JAR file in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. It's part of webapp's default classpath. You don't need to register every JAR file individually then, even not in Eclipse's buildpath (at least, if the project was properly setup as *Dynamic Web Project*).

Comment: I prefer not to have multiple copies of the jar files on the file system. I tried adding the references to catalina.properties the way I had it before, but the file keeps reverting back to it's original state (I presume this is eclipse doing this). Is there some way to permanaenty modify catalina.properties?

Comment: Ah right, now the *actual* problem is much clearer. You need to configure Eclipse to take over Tomcat instead of having a copy of it in its workspace. Doubleclick Tomcat entry in *Servers* view. Under *Server Locations*, select *Use Tomcat installation* (first remove all projects and publish Tomcat!). This way you can edit the `catalina.properties` the way you want without letting Eclipse to have a local copy.

Comment: Is there a drawback to setting up the configuration this way? I would think they provide that option for a reason.

Comment: To untouch the existing Tomcat instance/configuration. But that makes imo no sense for local development with a single IDE.

Comment: In the properties of the tomcat server in eclipse (right click and go into properties), which location should I use - [workspace metadata] or /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost?

Comment: Depends. Use the Servers project if you want to be able to commit/push/pull the server config into some repository. Otherwise, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @BalusC Is this still how you would set this up for Eclipse Helios? I can't seem to get to the screen you describe from my tomcat instance under the server tab.